# How to get whole number from decimal using Format String?

Tags: c#, .net

as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-decimal-d-format-specifier)

> The "D" (or decimal) format specifier converts a number to a string of
>   decimal digits (0-9), prefixed by a minus sign if the number is
>   negative. This format is supported only for integral types.

so it supports integral types.

However it does not work with decimal

```
var val = 1234.00M;

// line below throws exception `Format specifier was invalid.`
string.Format("{0:D}", val);

// line below throws exception `Format specifier was invalid.`
val.ToString("D");
```

However if i change `val` type from `decimal` to `integer` then it works.

**Question**
Is decimal not integral type?
How do i get only whole number part from decimal? (I know i can do it using Math.Truncate(val) but i am looking if it can be done using `DataFormatString`)

Comment: *This format is supported only for integral types.* - Integral type is integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is decimal not integral type?

Decimal is not an integral type. Decimal is a floating point type.

I suspect that you do not know what the word "integral" means. The "integers" are the whole numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3, and their negatives, -1, -2, -3, and so on.  They have no fractional parts.

Decimals are called "decimals" because they contain a fractional part which has a power of ten on the bottom, hence "deci", ten.

Thus decimals are not integral types. The integral types in C# are defined as `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `short`, `ushort`, `byte` and `sbyte`.

"Normal" floats -- `double` and `float` -- have a fractional part which has a power of two on the bottom. These are "binary" floats.

> How do i get only whole number part from decimal? (I know i can do it using Math.Truncate(val) but i am looking if it can be done using DataFormatString)

Since decimal is a floating point type you can use the fixed-point type specifier, `F`. See the documentation for details.

You might wonder what the difference is between "fixed point" and "floating point".  `decimal`, `double` and `float` all have the property that the bottom of the fraction can vary, or "float".  That is, a decimal could be `123.45` or `123.456` or `123.456789`.  The documentation calls the formatter a "fixed point" formatter because once you say how many digits are after the decimal point, that's the number of digits you're going to get.  If you use `F3` on `123.45` you'll get `123.450`; the number of places is "fixed".

Answer (score 11):

> How do i get only whole number part from decimal? (I know i can do it using Math.Truncate(val) but i am looking if it can be done using DataFormatString)

You can specify how many decimal places you want in the format string. If you place a `0` it means show the digit or show a 0 (in otherwords, show *something* in this placeholder), and if you use a `#` it means show this many significant digits if they exist (and if there are more, then the number will be rounded to this many digits). If you don't include a decimal point, it will only show you the number portion:

```
decimal x = 123.45M;

Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("0"));  // Output: 123   
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("0.0"));  // Output: 123.5   <- note there is rounding
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("0.00"));  // Output: 123.45
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("0.000"));  // Output: 123.450
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("#.###"));  // Output: 123.45
```

Note that there is rounding that will take place, which may cause unexpected results:

```
Console.WriteLine(123.9.ToString("0"));  // This will output 124
```

---

Another way to get the whole number part from a decimal is to cast it to an integer:

```
int wholeNumberPart = (int)1.9999M;  // result is '1'
```

Answer (score 2):

`D` is for integral types - integer, long, etc. Use `F0` for fixed point, with 0 places after the decimal.